# better nuxt vuex workflow?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

So...
I am developing a app with Nuxt

I have this following structure for my front-end but I don't know if this is the right way to do it,

basically I am dispatching VueX actions

`component.vue`

```
await this.$store.dispatch('auth/login', {email, password})
```

In auth/login vuex module I am doing this:

`store/auth.js`

```
    async login({commit}, {email, password}){
        try {
            let user = await this.$repositories.auth.login({email, password})
            await commit('SET_AUTH_INSTANCE', user)
            await commit('SET_AUTH_TOKEN', user.token)
        } catch (error) {

        }
    },
```

What am I actually asking...

Should I change the business logic? Should I call the repository API's in vue components and dispatching actions only with the payload so I can commit them ?

for example:

`component.vue`

```
let user = await this.$repositories.auth.login({email, password})
await this.$store.dispatch('auth/login', user)
```

`store/auth.js`

```
    async login({commit}, user){
        try {
            await commit('SET_AUTH_INSTANCE', user)
            await commit('SET_AUTH_TOKEN', user.token)
        } catch (error) {

        }
    },
```

Comment: If you assume that only repository can return user data, then I think better is to keep this in one action. But if there will be cases that you will get user data from different place, then you can use second aproach

Comment: I need to reuse some repository API's in other components and I can't use store, I went with the second approach, calling API's in components and setting the state with payload

Comment: do you know the nuxtServerInit? take a look at https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action.

Comment: some days ago, i have create a code example with a little vuex schema. Take a look in my answer to check if this is help to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59287712.

Comment: I will recommend going with the first way where you are doing API requests in vuex action. Which will help you to reuse the API whenever you want to hit again and your component code will be clean in that case. 
I will also recommend modularizing Vuex and Requiring Vuex as per route/page/lazy- loading of vuex Module